# Inserting a property with objects into a dataframe to extract as a JSON string

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm setting up a process that extracts a JSON response from an API. Then turning that into a dataframe to run logic over it to create a new JSON body to send as a POST to another API endpoint.

The issue I am having is that I can't work out how to format it correctly.

This is what is looks like this is generated from a dataframe

```
{
"id" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"permitted" : [ "SUMMARY" ],
"archived" : null,
"description" : "some string",
"name" : "some string",
"organisationBy" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"organisationFor" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"windowStart" : 1501642773871,
"templateSets" : [ "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ]
}
```

What I need to know is what columns and values I need to add to a dataframe to get the results below:

```
{
  "id" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "permitted" : [ "SUMMARY" ],
  "archived" : null,
  "description" : "some string",
  "name" : "some string",
  "organisationBy" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "organisationFor" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "windowStart" : 1501642773871,
  "templates" : [ {
    "name" : "some string",
    "type" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "template" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  } ],
  "templateSets" : [ "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ]
}
```

Comment: If what you get back from your df is true, then all you need is column named `templates`, with `{ "name" : "some string", "type" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "template" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
 }` in the column. (including the "{", so each cell will be a dict)

Comment: I will give this a try. I think I tried this before except I tried inserting directing inserting into the json I think or dict, and it would carry over the "\" with it as well.